# Quantifiers and If then statements

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

There are two sentences $\varphi(u), \psi(u)$ with common variable $u$. Are they equivalent: $\forall u[\varphi(u) \rightarrow \psi(u)]$ and $[\varphi(u) \rightarrow \psi(u)]$?

Comment: If they are sentences then u is a free variable, did you mean that they are formulas?

Comment: Probably, it is necessay that you clarify a little bit your question; are you asking for "prvably equivalent" i.e. if $\vdash ∀u[φ(u)→ψ(u)] \leftrightarrow [φ(u)→ψ(u)]$ ? or about *logical* (or *semantical*) equivalence ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\forall u[\varphi(u) \rightarrow \psi(u)]$ doesn't have any free variables. It's either true or false, depending on what $\varphi$ and $\psi$ say.

On the other hand, $[\varphi(u) \rightarrow \psi(u)]$ has a free variable (namely $u$). It doesn't have a set truth value untill you give it a concrete $u$ to evaluate, and then it is true or false only depending on that specific $u$.

This means that $\forall u[\varphi(u) \rightarrow \psi(u)]$ is true iff $[\varphi(u) \rightarrow \psi(u)]$ *always* evaluates to true, no matter what $u$ is; that is what $\forall$ *means*, after all.

Comment: Sentence doesn't have to have a truth value. It's just a formula without free variables.

Answer (score 0):

By definition: 
We say that formulas $\phi (x_1,x_2, \dots , x_n)$ and $\psi (x_1,x_2, \dots , x_n)$ are equivalent, if: $\forall_{x_1}\forall_{x_2} \dots \forall_{x_n} \ \phi (x_1,x_2, \dots , x_n) \leftrightarrow \psi (x_1,x_2, \dots , x_n)$ is a rule of logic. In other words two formulas are equivalent if theirs universal closures are equivalent. Applying it to our problem, we obtain:
$$\forall_u [\forall_u[\phi (u) \rightarrow \psi(u)]] \leftrightarrow [\forall_u[\phi (u) \rightarrow \psi(u)],$$
which is obviously true.

Comment: Can we use the expression $\forall u [\forall u \varphi]]$?

Comment: Yes but the repetition doesn't change anything, atleast under the definitions i have in logic (Model Theory) coursebook.

Comment: One more question: suppose that there is a sentence $\varphi$ that doesn't have $u$ as a free variable, is $\forall u \varphi $ equivalent to $\varphi$?

Comment: The universal closure of an equivalence is not necessarily equivalent to the corresponding equivalence between universal closures. E.g., $\forall x_1 \dots \forall x_n(\phi(x_1 \dots x_n) \rightarrow \forall x_1 \dots \forall x_n \phi (x_1 \dots x_n))$ is equivalent to $\exists x_1 \dots \exists x_n \phi(x_1 \dots x_n) \rightarrow \forall x_1 \dots \forall x_n \phi (x_1 \dots x_n)$. Else (more likely?) we are presumed working in some unknown theory, in which case the answer would be "maybe" (depends on the theory).

Comment: It is the case that $\phi(x)$ is valid if and only if $\forall x \phi(x)$ is valid, but that is different from saying that the equivalence between them is valid. The equivalence in $\top \vdash \phi (x) $ if and only if $\top \vdash \forall x \phi(x)$ is an equivalence in the metatheory. The equivalence in (the invalid) $\top \vdash \phi (x) \leftrightarrow \forall \phi(x)$ is a material equivalence in the theory with no non-logical axioms.

Comment: If (as is sometimes done) by "sentence" one means "contains no free variable" (in contradistinction with "formula"), then the answer to original question is "yes". I didn't give that possibility any credence, I suppose because $u$ was explicitly included in the parentheses. And are $\phi$ and $\psi$ to be taken to be (unary) predicate symbols? If not, one can't say definitely that the equivalence is not valid (obviously then the equivalence would depend on the formulas substituted). It's easy to jump to answering wrong question or the most interesting elegant question like what was asked.